# Include dynamic JSON data in Angular7 app

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular-cli, angular7

I am using both `ng serve --watch` and `ng build --watch`. With ng build, it will use my index.html file, but with ng serve, it seems to ignore it.

Right now, I am rendering some dynamic JSON in the index.html file like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ApiApp</title>
  <base href="<%=base%>">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

   <script type="text/javascript">

       const appData = JSON.parse('<%=json%>');

   </script>

  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

the above works with `ng build` but not `ng serve`, since `ng serve` doesn't seem to incorporate this file.

Is there a better way to send dynamic JSON to an Angular7 app when the app is first loaded? My server can render the JSON to the `index.html` in production, but during development with `ng serve`, it's not working so well.

Answer (score 0):

For now I just abandoned ng-serve, and just use `ng build --watch`, and then use static-server (an npm CLI tool), like so:

```
"static-server": "cd dist/my-app && static-server --index index.html"
```

and my index.html looks like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ApiApp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

   <script type="text/javascript">

     define('app-data',() => {
       console.log('retrieving app-data...');

       let val = null;
       try{
         val = JSON.parse('<%=json%>')
       }
       catch(err){
         val = {routes: [1,2,3,4,5].map(v => ({val:v}))};
       }

       return {
         value: val
       }
     });

   </script>

  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

requirejs allows me to easily load dynamic code, haven't figured out how to do that with Angular yet.